# AWS EKS - cannot access apache httpd behind a LoadBalancer

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I've deployed an apache httpd server in a container and am attempting to expose it externally via a LoadBalancer. Although I can log on to the local host and get the expected response (curl -X GET localhost) when I try and access the external URL exposed by the load balancer I get an Empty reply from server:

```
curl -X GET ad8d14ea0ba9611e8b2360afc35626a3-553331517.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:5000
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Any idea what I am missing - is there some kind of additional redirection going on that I'm unaware of?

The yaml is here:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apache
labels:
  app: apache
spec:
  replicas: 1
selector:
  matchLabels:
    pod: apache
template:
  metadata:
    name: apachehost
    labels:
      pod: apache
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: apache
        image: myrepo/apache2
      ports:
      - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apache
labels:
  app: apache
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    pod: apache
  ports:
    - name: port1
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 80
```

Comment: Are your pods running? From the AWS side is your load balancer target groups or instances in service?

Comment: did you get any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

1.Check your pod running.

2.Check aws IAM and security group also may be 5000 port not open for public.Use curl command in kubernet master and check port.

3.Share a pod logs

Comment: Hi - the pod is running, because when I open a shell on it and curl localhost I get the expected response.  Port 5000 is open, because I can access a simple web app (in python/flask) on that port.   I didn't post the pod logs because they show nothing other than that apache has started - but it is not receiving any requests.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this issue? I am facing a similiar issue.

Answer (score 0):

check on your aws load balancer for open port of 5000 in security group for LB. as in bound rule.

check for inbound rule of load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

If your pods are running on Fargate the load balancer service will not work: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/load-balancing.html